# Jquery call second autocomplete after completion of one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to use two autocomplete function on two fields. When i typed in one field autocomplete ajax call is happened and it shows the result set. But when i select the the value i want to fire another autocomplete on second field which use the value of first field, make a ajax call and then show the dropdown and i will select the desired value.
 Below is my code:

No this is not working. i added

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax( {
          url: "index.php",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        } );
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
             var tt =  ui.item.value;
             $( "#animal" ).autocomplete({
                  source: "ajax.php?var="+tt,
                  minLength: 0,
                  success: function( data ) {
                    response( data );
                  }
                });


        //log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
      }
    } );
```

After selection of first drop box i want to auto fire second autocomplete box.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your input fields,

`$("#firstInput").autocomplete({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        $("#secondInput").html(ui.item.value);
    }
});`

Comment: No it is not working. i have modified my question with more details.